# Обрезать окно другого приложения

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть звонилка, внизу у нее постоянно реклама висит, что раздражает. Возникла идея не блочить сервер рекламы, а просто обрезать снизу, либо серый квадратик поставить. Можно это как нибудь на c# реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: есть только установочные файлы, больше ничего? Или вы используете сторонний контрол?

Comment: Вы понмаете, что вы просто скинули скриншот непонятно чего и спрашиваете, можно ли это непонятно что пофиксить?

Comment: Это стороннее приложение. Доступа к исходному коду у меня нет. Просто интересно если мы знаем нахождение формы на рабочем столе и ее размеры, можно ли что то разместить на этой форме не влезая в ее код?

Comment: рабочем столе чего? Что за устройство? Какая ОС?

Comment: @tym32167 Думал если указал язык устройство и ОС подразумевалась. 7, 10 без разницы.

Comment: 7-10 что? Android? IOS? Не надо ничего подразумевать, пишите всю инфу прямо в вопросе. Я вот увидел скрин, и решил, что это что то про разработку для мобилок.

Comment: @tym32167, да скрин конечно похож) меня интересует масдай от 7 до 10

Comment: Приложение писано на шарпе?

Comment: Я к тому, что это все надо в вопросе указать

Comment: Я вот тоже подумал, что это мобильное приложение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, что тебе нужно сделать программу, которая бы отслеживала какое окно сейчас активное.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
{
    const int nChars = 256;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
    {
        return Buff.ToString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Если тайтл совпадает с тайтлом апликухи рекламу на которой нужно блочить, то тебе нужно отрисовать твою форму c FormBorderStyle = None и TopMost с учетом ширины активного окна и с учетом высоты рекламного блока. 
Логика этого -- на тебе, это не сложно.

Если же окно не активно -- то и рисовать прямоугольник(твою эту форму) не нужно вообще. Просто скрываешь ее полностью.

Единственное что я бы добавила - это то, что нужно НЕ делать твое окно активным если на него попали мышкой.

То есть при клике на твою форму нужно автоматом делать клик назад на ту форму которая только что была активной.

PS: Но честно, проще уже отследить к какому серваку прога обращается и внести этот сервак под 127.0.0.1 в hosts файл.